# Media query firing at wrong point on Firefox

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox, media-queries

A Wordpress site I'm working on has `1008px` as its main breakpoint and I have various media queries which are supposed to fire at this point. Everything works as expected in Chrome and Safari, however if I resize the screen on Firefox the media queries fire instead at 992px. The issue only seems to be related to CSS, as I have some jQuery functions that fire correctly at 1008px.

Below is an example of how I'm writing my media queries:

```
        @mixin mediaMin($minWidth) {
          @media (min-width: $minWidth) {
            @content;
          }
        }

        @mixin mediaMax($minWidth) {
          $maxWidth: ($minWidth - 1);
          @media (max-width: $maxWidth) {
            @content;
          }
        }

        .element {
            height: 100vh;

            @include mediaMax(1008px){
                height: 363px;
            }
        }
```

Does anybody have any idea on what could be causing the media queries to fire at the wrong point in Firefox?